# Работа с базой данных как вызвать первые 5 записей из бд?

Tags: python, sqlite

Есть база данных, в которой например 250 записей.
Нужно вывести первые 5

```
python 3
sqlite3
```

Comment: В SQL нет понятия первые/последние. Все зависит от результата сортировки

Answer (score 5):

```sql
SELECT
   column_list
FROM
   table 
LIMIT 5;
```

Большинство БД не гарантируют того, что SELECT вернёт строки в том порядке, в котором они были записаны. Соответственно, в реляционной алгебре отсутствует понятие первые и последние в абсолютном значении. Можно отсортировать данные по столбцам и вывести N верхних строк (после сортировки):

```sql
SELECT
   column_list
FROM
   table
ORDER BY column_1
LIMIT row_count;
```